Passing a `key` attribute from a native HTML element to a Vue/Nuxt widget
I'm developing a custom widget using Nuxt 3, and it's encapsulated within a shadow root. I need to pass an API key to this widget using the key attribute from a native HTML element like so:
<my-widget key="my-api-key"></my-widget>

However, in Vue 3 (which Nuxt 3 is based on), the key attribute is reserved for internal use. This means it's not available as a prop or accessible via $attrs in my component. For my use-case, keeping the key attribute is important in order to provide drop-in compatibility with the widget it replaces.
How can I use the key attribute in my widget?

It's unclear what is the actual implementation and which part is nuxt. You could read it from $el
